# running javascript place holders

Tags: javascript, php, input, placeholder

I have a site done in javascript that requires place holders once the "Save" button has been clicked in order to fill out a form with information...the save button and the address bar can be seen in the image below -

[image: IMG]

I want placeholders to appear when I click the "Save" button with information that I insert into a database. The second image below will hopefully prove my point better. You can see extra information that the address bar location is supposed to be calling - as exemplified with the following extension -?`id13=Roberto&id13=Roberto` after the japplications4.php file is being called.

[image: IMG]

As you can see in the link above - the extension after the filename should call certain data input as placeholders for the website - the information in the address bar can be seen as in the example below:

```
japplications4.php?id13=Roberto&id13=Roberto
```

Say for example, the data being inserted is the first name using the variable `$first_name` which I insert into the form with the column "first_name" - I've got the code below so that you will get a better idea of what I want to get done...

Here's the javascript code - in the header:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function validinput()
    {
    top.location="japplications4.php?id13="+document.getElementById("first_name").value+"&id13="+document.getElementById("first_name").innerHTML;

    document.getElementById('myform').submit(); 
    }



    </script>

here's the html code for the form field as as well:

            <H1 align="center"><p><br>JOB APPLICATION FORM</H1><p><br>
        <form id="myform" action="" align="center" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="div2">
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">
        <colgroup>
        <col span="1">
        </colgroup>

     <H2 align="center">FULL NAME</H2>
    <br>
    <tr>

     <td valign="top">

      <label for="first_name">First Name: </label>

     </td>

     <td valign="top">

      <input  type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) { echo $_POST['first_name']; } ?>" size="38">

     </td>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="submitd" onClick="validinput()" value="Save"/>Save</button>

</form>
```

Here is the section that I REALLY need help with:

```
    function validinput()
{
top.location="japplications4.php?id13="+document.getElementById("first_name").value+"&id13="+document.getElementById("first_name").innerHTML;

document.getElementById('myform').submit(); 
}
```

When the Save button is clicked, the valid input function is called. I want the address of the location bar to say `"japplications4.php?id13="+_______"`.
The blank information should be from the form field when I enter the First Name `- document.getElementById("first_name").innerHTML;`.

What do I do right now then to fix up this issue so that things can be solved?

I hope that you  can help me figure out this small problem...

Comment: anyone around to help out? or is everyone napping?

Comment: try to simplify your code and filter out the problem where you stuck at.... and what are you trying to do... I see a number of possible problems.

Comment: i need the address bar to change...the address bar/location bar will be the new place holder once I click the "Save" button...after i insert data in the form fields...ya feel me?

Comment: does anyone have an idea what i'm talking about? once I click the "Save" button, the onClick method will have to immediately change the URL in the address bar and use the data inputed as a place holder with a different extension as per the data fields that I've entered...

Comment: was no body able to answer this question for me?